# Is that method correct for solving this issue?

Tags: java

```
public static LinkedList<Double> list(Stack stack) {
        //create doubly linked list object
        LinkedList<Double> list = new LinkedList<>();

        // add double element to linked list as a test 
        list.add(22.5);
        list.add(8.5);
        list.add(3.5);
        list.add(4.5);

        // check if stack is not empty then add doubly linked list elements to the Stack
        // then pritn stack elements and return this list
        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Stack is not Empty");
        } else {
            stack.addAll(list);
            for (Object stack1 : stack) {
                System.out.println(stack1);
            }

        }

        return list;
    }
```

Write java method that takes a stack as an argument  and fill its elements in doubly linked list and return this list.

Comment: A `LinkedList<Double>` is not really the same as "doubly linked list". :)

Comment: It should be other way round. Instead of populating the stack using the list. You need to populate list with stack. Also as @aioobe mentioned you should not get confused with the doubly linked list using LinkedList<Double>

Comment: The question is not phrased clearly. It's possible you are actually being asked to do the opposite (i.e. get elements from the input Stack into the LinkedList that the method returns).

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen `stack.addAll(list)` means you are adding all the contents of list into stack.

Comment: @aioobe true, but every `java.util.LinkedList<Double>` is also a doubly linked list. :) It's the other direction that's not always true.

Comment: Given the simplicity of the task, are you not sure you are supposed to write your own implementations of both a `Stack` and a doubly-linked `List`?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen refer the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) for clear understanding on this, Stack extends Vector and uses the same addAll implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is

```
public static <V> List<V> list(<Stack<V> stack) {
    return new LinkedList<>(stack);
}
```

However, I suspect you are missing some requirement in your homework. e.g. did they expect you to implement you own doubly linked list and/or stack?